# whereBetween and orWhere to get data in a date range

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get date range created_at here is my example table

```
id    status  created_at
1      1      2018-05-10 10:53:54
2      2      2018-05-10 10:53:54
3      2      2018-05-9 11:53:54
```

in My controller

```
$this->to = 2018-05-10;
$this->from = 2018-05-09;
Table::whereBetween('created_at', [$this->from, $this->to]) 
                            ->orwhere('created_at', 'like', '%' .$this->to. '%')
                            ->where('status', 2);
```

In this query it print all data which have status 1 and 2 how can i get only status2

I try to die_dump my sql i get my query like this

```
select * from `table` where `created_at` between '2018-05-09' and '2018-05-10' or `created_at` like '%2018-05-10%' and `status` = '2'
```

Comment: Date rage ? I get angry about June 4th.

Comment: Just get rid of the `->orwhere(...)` it doesn't add anything to the query anyway as it just repeats the end condition of the `between`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try subquery for `whereBetween('created_at', [$this->from, $this->to])` and `->orwhere('created_at', 'like', '%' .$this->to. '%')`

```
$from = $this->from;
$to = $this->to;
Table::where('status', 2)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($from,$to) {
                    $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
                                ->orwhere('created_at', 'like', '%' .$to. '%');
            });
```

Comment: why when i put ->where(function ($query) .... It said Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->'

Answer (score 1):

```
 Table::where(function($q) use ($from,$to)){
      $q->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
        ->orwhere('created_at', 'like', '%' .$to. '%')
    }->where('status', 2);
```

You can search "nested/sub query eloquent laravel" for more information